# What do I need to change in Netbeans so that it builds a hybrid JavaFX application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javafx

I've written a simulation with animations in Swing (and awt components) and graphing in JavaFX. However, I would like to build this in Netbeans so that all components are build correctly. I read on Oracle's site that I need to build with certain parameters to enable e.g. Swing functionality in a JavaFX application, but as I don't have any experience with packaging, I have no idea how to do this. I created my project in Netbeans as a "Java Application", but added the JavaFX functionality much later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you start looking here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation_2-2/javafx-installation-mac.htm

Eventually you will find this:

https://netbeans.org/kb/72/java/javafx-setup.html

Projects done in a IDE can be confusing for those who do not know very well how to manipulate them. What you can do now is take a look at the link I gave you so you can learn to create and manipulate a JavaFX project. Then what you can do is create a new JavaFX project and import the classes you were using in the previous project. To copy the classes, you can simply import your class files with NetBeans, or you can copy and paste the files from your computer into Netbeans project that Netbeans will recognize your files.

Remember that at the end of all, the projects reflect the existing files on your computer. What an IDE primarily does for you is just to help you manipulate these files.

**OBS**: To learn how to use Netbeans with scene builder, look at the following link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-nb.htm

Hope this helps. As always, we're here. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks so much... I'll try those links and your instructions, and if I get it right, I'll get back to you and mark the answer!

Comment: If you use [java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) you won't have to worry about most of that as jfxrt is included in the default java platform.